# Uploaded File is not moving in specified folder in php

Tags: php, file

I have a php file named abstract_submission and to process the form in that file I created submitted_abstract php file. but move_uploaded file function does not working. for files I created a folder named submissions. Does anyone have a solution to this?

I tried shifting insert query up and down in if statement but it doesn't work.

```php
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost",MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASSWORD,"svavpo_phicon");


    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup-errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $edit_state = false;


    if(isset($_POST['sybmitabs']))
    {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $subm_category = $_POST['subm_category'];
        $main_category = $_POST['main_category'];
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $author = $_POST['author'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $reference = $_POST['reference'];


        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $target = "submissions/".basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `sub_abstract`(`name`, `email`, `category`, `subm_category`, `main_category`, `title`, `author`, `body`, `reference`, `file`) VALUES ('$name','$email','$category','$subm_category','$main_category','$title','$author','$body','$reference','$file')";


        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target))
        {
            echo "errro in updating db";
        }
        else
        {

            echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Abstract Submitted Succesfully !');
        window.location.href='../abstract_submission.php';
        </script>");
        }



    }

?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: So what happens? Error messages? Also, your logic is off. You're currently echoing `errro in updating db` if the file was successfully moved, which makes no sense. Don't you mean to have it the other way around? You should first move the file and if it worked, insert into db.

Comment: Try with the full path - ie `$target = __DIR__ . "/submissions/" . basename( $_FILES['file']['name'] );`